# Do you know why not AR.js in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

Having some problems with iPhone, apart from the problem of accepting the permissions for ar.js that most will not access, the button for AR does not appear and when you press VR it stays blocked. Have you had these problems and do you know how to solve them? Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: The "AR" button is launching an WebXR session, and is not connected to [ar.js](https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/) which doesn't utilize webxr. Do you have issues with arjs on your iphone?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, in my case I "forced" the button to appear, but it doesn't work at all...I did some web searching, and the problem appear to be with the iOS system (like always), they didn't have the webxr api enabled...